# Minkowski's Inequality for Convolutions, Proof when $p = \infty$

Tags: analysis, inequality, harmonic-analysis, convolution, integral-inequality

I'm having a silly time trying to prove the "simple" case of:

$g \in \|L\|_{1}$ and $f \in \|L\|_{\infty}$

Then it holds that:

$\| f \ast g \|_{L^\infty} \leq \|g\|_{L^1}\|f\|_{L^\infty}$

Where $\ast$ is the convolution. This is one of the edge cases in Minkowki's Inequality for convolutions when $p=1$.

So far I have only substituted the definition of infinity norm on both sides but it did not enlighten me at all.

Edit: here it is explicitly,

$\| f \ast g \|_{L^\infty} = inf\{B>0: \mu(\{x:| \int g(y)f(y^{-1}x) d\mu (y) |>B\})=0\}$

and on the other hand:

$\|g\|_{L^1}\|f\|_{L^\infty} = \int |g| \mu \cdot inf\{B>0: \mu(\{x:| \int f(y) d\mu (y) |>B\})=0\}$

Comment: I can get $\|\cdot\|_1< \|\cdot\|_\infty \|\cdot\|_1$ but I am not sure yours is true

Comment: Hint: Write explicitly $|f\ast g(x)|$ and estimate naively...

Comment: @marmouset I am looking at Loukas Grafakos's harmonic analysis and he claims it is true

Comment: @mathbeing I have written it explicitly, maybe I am missing some property of the ess.sup?

Comment: Under the given conditions, $f\ast g$ is continuous, so the essential supremum is the actual supremum. Just write down $$\lvert (f\ast g)(x)\rvert = \Biggl\lvert \int g(y)f(y^{-1}x)\,d\mu(y)\Biggr\rvert$$ and make the most obvious estimates.

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand I can apply the triangle inequality to that, but why is the ess.sup = sup, and am I using the wrong definition for this to work? For me this entire thin is still inside the measure afterwards.

Comment: The tactical mistake is to bother with the definition at all. What you need is a property of the essential supremum, namely that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$, except maybe on some null set. Then $\lvert gf\rvert \leqslant \lvert g\rvert\cdot\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Oh! That is indeed trivial haha, thank you very much for putting up! If you paste your comment in a solution I will accept it of course =)